# Background image shrinking but not div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new and am completely stumped by something. I have div with a background image. When the window is resized, the background image shrinks in height once the window is adjusted smaller than the width of the actual photo. I like the way this looks, but the div container is remaining the same height. Any text I have is not remaining vertically centered to the background picture (which is changing height), it is remaining centered to the div (which is not), so the text is floating off the image. Is there a way to make the container shrink in the same way that the background image is so everything stays centered?

```css
#mainpic {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url("http://www.aclefproductions.com/Images/pianoedit6.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainpic">
  <h3>Hello</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id = "mainpic">
  <h3>Hello</h3>
  <img src="http://www.aclefproductions.com/Images/pianoedit6.jpg">
</div>

 #mainpic {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  }

  #mainpic img{
    width: 100%;
  }


  #mainpic h3{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /*To account for the width and hight of the h3*/
    margin: 0;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4p3gek5x/

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's what you want? See http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/dXvzBq?editors=1100#

```
#mainpic {
          margin: 0;
          width: 100%;
          background-image: url("http://www.aclefproductions.com/Images/pianoedit6.jpg");
          background-size: 100%;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          overflow: hidden;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
}
#mainpic h3{
          height:400px;
}
```